# How to get form action WITH PARAMS with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, meta-search

Let's me explain a little. The goal is to save urls in history state when form submitted. Form has get method and remote submit. If I try to get action via `attr` method it's always be static. But when I submit the form url looks like `/job?type=1&category_id=4&tags=foo,bar` because it has get method.

So how can I get exactly this url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way you can get what you want.

```
var url=$('form').attr('action')+'?'+$('form').serialize();
```